# How to save String input from user and terminate after the second line return '\n''\n'

Tags: assembly, mips

Good day,

I'm trying to record a user input through a system service number 8 on MARS_4.5.

The input is a String and it must accept newline '\n'.
The problem is that a syscall 8 will stop reading on newline, as fgets() does on UNIX.

The only solution I have in mind right now is to go through writing a file and then reading it to manipulate my String thereafter.

I would like to know if there is a more obvious way to do this.

Thank you for your suggestions,

Karl

```
//prompt
la   $a0, prompt_msg  
li   $v0, 4    
syscall

//save input in buffer
la   $a0, buffer
li   $a1, 300      
li   $v0, 8         
syscall

//display input
la $a0, input_display
li $v0, 4
syscall
la $a0, buffer
syscall
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, this is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: Turned my comment into an answer, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[MARS has a read-file system call](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/MARS/Help/SyscallHelp.html) that can read from stdin (fd=0) like POSIX `read(fd, buf, max_len)`. $v0=14 / syscall.

This might read more than two newlines, but your code that parses the input can stop looping wherever you want.

Or you could just use the read-string fgets system call (`$v0=8`) until the user user presses return on an empty line, resulting in the first byte of input being `'\n'`.

---

Other than that; I don't think the limited toy syscall API that MARS provides has a way to query if a char is available, so your choices are blocking until the user hits a second newline, or leaving it unread.

In real OSes, there's usually a way to do a non-blocking query to find out if any input is waiting to be read.  (e.g. POSIX `select()`, or `fcntl` to set a file descriptor to O_NONBLOCK so read will set `errno=EAGAIN` without blocking if there's no input ready.  And raw vs. cooked TTY letting you read characters before the user hits return).  But MARS / SPIM system calls are only suitable for programs that don't do sophisticated user-interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, before I mark it as such, can you briefly explain to me how you would go on about making fgets() stop when the user presses return on an empty line? I don't see how an empty line can be created if fgets() stops on newline or at n-1. Again, thank you.

Comment: @KarlEmm: IIRC, it *reads* the newline, otherwise it would still be in the input buffer.  But if not, detect that via return-value (length) = 0.